Finding the Symmetric Point to $ P = (x_0, y_0) $ Across the Line $Ax + By + C = 0$
How to find the coordinates of the point symmetric to point P = {x0, y0} with respect to the lineAx + By + C == 0?
My method is:
ClearAll[reflectPoint];
reflectPoint[{x0_, y0_}, {A_, B_, C_}] := 
 Module[{distance, factor}, distance = A x0 + B y0 + C;
  factor = 2*distance/(A^2 + B^2);
  {x0 - A*factor, y0 - B*factor}]

reflectPoint[{x0, y0}, {A, B, C}]


Is there another way to solve this symmetry problem?

Did you try Solve[A*x + B*y + C == 0 /. {x -> (x0 + x1)/2, y -> (y0 + y1)/2}, {x1,    y1}] or/and Reduce[A*x + B*y + C == 0 /. {x -> (x0 + x1)/2, y -> (y0 + y1)/2}, {x1,    y1}] ?  think the question is a hit.

Once again, I don't see your effort in understanding the code you've copied. (-1)
Hyperplane:
How can the errors in this Solid Geometry code be corrected?
RegionNearest:
How to make moving point and moving circle play automatically?
RotationTransform:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/307268/1871
RotationTransform[π, Hyperplane[{A, B}, -C]~RegionNearest~{x0, y0}]@{x0, y0}


The implicit equation of a line: a x+b y+c==0. Note that {a,b} is a vector perpendicular to the line. Further note, the reflected point is twice as far away from the original point as the line along the perpendicular {a,b}. With this:
Clear[reflect];
reflect[p0 : {x0_, y0_}, {a_, b_, c_}] := 
Module[{n},
   n = Normalize[{a, b}];
   p0 - 2 (n . (p0 + {c/a, 0})) n 
];

Addendum
Here is an application:
Manipulate[
 p0 = {1, y};
 li = {3, 4, 5};
 p = reflect[p0, li];
 d = 4;
 ContourPlot[li . {x, y, 1} == 0, {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[{p0, p}]}, Axes -> True],
 {{y, 0}, -2, 2}]


]

I'm sorry, but your code involves syntax mistake, and this method is wrong.

Still, the method is wrong. Just test e.g. reflect[{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}] and compare the output with mine or OP's.

You are right I made an error.
